# The complement - in the mathematical sense of the word - of "this" in jQuery

Tags: jquery, selector, this

I'm making a navigation menu such that when a navigation button is clicked, it obtains a "selected" class, while that class is simultaneously removed from the other buttons. (I also fade in and out the corresponding pages). The bare-bones code is:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
ul li a.selected {font-weight:bold;}
div.page {position:absolute;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("div.page:not(:first)").hide();   // hide all pages except the home page

    $("ul li a").click(function(){
        var previous=window.location.hash;
        var selected=$(this).attr("href");
        if (previous != selected) {
            $("div.page"+previous).fadeOut();
            $("div.page"+selected).fadeIn();
            }
        $(this).addClass("selected")
        $("ul li a").not(this).removeClass("selected");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="page" id="home">This is my home page.</div>
<div class="page" id="portfolio">This is my portfolio page.</div>
<div class="page" id="contact">This is my contact page.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Although this code does work, I'm a "code aesthetic" and dislike typing $("ul li a") again refer to the navigation buttons; since I already typed this at the beginning of the chain, it seems I should be able to obtain it in a general way without retyping. In essence, I want to select the relative complement of "this" within the original selected set "ul li a". Is there a general way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean `$(this).siblings()`?

Comment: @mblase75: the `a`'s aren't siblings of each other.

Answer (score 3):

Saving it into a variable:

```
$elements = $("ul li a");
$elements.click(function(){
    // ...
    $elements.not(this).removeClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replies! The answer (actually there are several more elegant ways) is quite simple, haha, but sometimes you need a fresh perspective :)

Answer (score 1):

You could (*should*) cache the result of the `$('ul li a')` the first time, and use it the second;

```
var elements = $("ul li a").click(function(){
    var previous=window.location.hash;
    var selected=$(this).attr("href");
    if (previous != selected) {
        var previousId=previous.substring(1);   // remove the hash symbol
        var selectedId=selected.substring(1);
        $("div.page#"+previousId).fadeOut();
        $("div.page#"+selectedId).fadeIn();
        }
    $(this).addClass("selected")
    elements.not(this).removeClass("selected");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the 'selected' class first from everything, and then add it to $(this):

```
$('.selected').removeClass('selected')
$(this).addClass('selected')
```

That way you can be sure not to affect any unrelated ul>li>a's...

Answer (score 1):

No -- unless the other items are all siblings of `$(this)`, then jQuery has no way of knowing what that selector contained unless you cache it.

Caching is a good idea any time you use a selector more than once:

```
var $sel = $("ul li a"); // cache
$sel.click(function(){
    // other code ...
    $sel.not(this).removeClass("selected");
});
```